# A system should return a positive number, but python always return Y as a negative number while it shouldn't

Tags: python, system, algebra

```
def cramer_input(): #Chiede l'input dei coefficienti della colonna x, y e i termini noti.

    #Variabili

    global cx1
    global cx2
    global cy1
    global cy2
    global tn1
    global tn2
    print('Inserisci il coefficiente di X della prima riga')
    cx1 = float(input("INPUT > "))
    print("Inserisci il coefficiente di X nella seconda riga")
    cx2 = float(input("INPUT > "))
    print("Inserisci il coefficiente di Y nella prima riga")
    cy1 = float(input("INPUT > "))
    print("Inserisci il coefficiente di Y nella seconda riga")
    cy2 = float(input("INPUT > "))
    print("Inserisci il termine noto della prima riga")
    tn1 = float(input("INPUT > "))
    print("Inserisci il termine noto della seconda riga")
    tn2 = float(input("INPUT > "))

    dxy = ((cx1) * (cy2)) - ((cx2) * (cy1))
    dxp = ((tn1) * (cy2)) - ((tn2) * (cy1))
    dyp = ((tn1) * (cx2)) - ((tn2) * (cx1))

    dx = dxp / dxy
    dy = dyp / dxy

    print("X = " + str(dx))
    print("Y = " + str(dy))

    qr = input("Chiudere (q) o rieseguire (R) ?")
    while qr == "r" or "R":
        cramer_input()
    else:
        quit()

def menu():
    print("Titolo: Risoluzione di sistemi lineari con il metodo di Cramer")
    print("Autore: Francesco Parisio")
    print("Digita I per iniziare, Q per chiudere.")
    iq = input("INPUT I/Q > ")
    if iq == "I" or "i":
        cramer_input()
    elif iq == "Q" or "q":
        quit()

menu()
```

I tried using this algorithm to resolve a linear system. When i press ENTER it work, but the `Y` is always negative and I dont want that, in a solution of `(1;4)`, the `4` is always `-4`.

I used this example:

```
3x -y = -1
```

{

```
x + y = 5
```

This should return 1;4, but it return 1;-4

Help me please, thanks.

Comment: `if iq == "I" or "i":` is wrong, but I don't think this has anything to do with the problem.

Comment: It should be `if iq == "I" or iq == "i":`. Or `if lower(iq) == "i":`

Comment: See http://www.mathnstuff.com/math/algebra/adeterm.htm - columns of the 2x2 matrix for the determinant `dyp` are swapped in your program.